# Understanding why the empty set is closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> **Definition**. A set is called closed if its complement in $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

In my lecture notes it says: $\emptyset$ is closed because $\emptyset = \emptyset \setminus \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is open. I think there is a typo because $\emptyset \neq \emptyset \setminus \mathbb{R}$, right? It should be $\emptyset = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Can you please check this?

Comment: $(\phi)^c = \mathbb R \setminus \phi = \mathbb R$ , which is open in $\mathbb R$ .so $\phi$ is closed according to your definition.

Comment: @HirenGarai What is the $\phi$?

Comment: Its the Empty set.

Comment: @HirenGarai: $\phi$ is a lower-case Greek letter phi. If you squint at it it may look slightly like $\varnothing$, which is the symbol for the empty set, but it is _not_ that symbol.

Comment: @HenningMakholm And here I though $\varnothing$ looks more like the diameter symbol than like $\emptyset$ ;)

Comment: Also note this is consistent with other ways to define *closed*. E.g., the empty set trivially includes all of its limit points.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What is a diameter symbol ?

Comment: @A---B See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Diameter_symbol, commonly used in [Engineering Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing_abbreviations_and_symbols#D), for one

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen `\varnothing` vs `\diameter`.

Answer (score 25):

It's both correct and a typo.

That is:

- The **useful** statement is "$\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\emptyset$": since $\mathbb{R}$ is open, this means the complement of $\emptyset$ (in $\mathbb{R}$) is open - so $\emptyset$ is closed. This is (presumably) what the author meant to write.
- However, it is **true** that $\emptyset=\emptyset\setminus\mathbb{R}$; it's just not helpful here. Remember that "$A\setminus B$" is the set of all things in $A$ which aren't in $B$. Well, there are no things in $\emptyset$ which aren't in $\mathbb{R}$ (in fact, there are no things in $\emptyset$ at all!), so $\emptyset\setminus\mathbb{R}=\emptyset$. *(I'm pointing this out because you ask whether $\emptyset\setminus\mathbb{R}\not=\emptyset$, at the end of your question.)*

Comment: For the first bullet the definition that you seem to use is (retaining OP's phrasing of the definition of 'closed' set), "A set is called closed if it can be expressed as the complement of some set $A$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$." So I don't think that the author meant to write what you suggest him/her to (presumably) write simply because the definition that OP gives doesn't agree exactly in its intention with what I have just written (although it can be proved).

Comment: @user170039 Whoops, read too fast - good catch.

Comment: OP suggested the from $\emptyset = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ which is equivalent to the form $\mathbb{R} =  \mathbb{R} \setminus \emptyset$ in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The complement of $\emptyset$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \emptyset$ which is equal to $\mathbb{R}$. And $\emptyset$ is closed **in $\mathbb{R}$** because $\mathbb{R}$ is open **in $\mathbb{R}$**.

Furthermore, even though $\emptyset=\emptyset\setminus \mathbb{R}$, that doesn't let's us conclude that $\emptyset$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is probably a typo. It should be $\emptyset=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb R$.